Detecting SwiftUI drag Began event
I want to detect where the drag gesture first began. I have a subview that is only 20 points wide. I add a Drag Gesture to the super view and want to move around this subview only if the drag gesture start location at the beginning of the gesture was within 20 points of the location of this subview. I do not want to add drag gesture to this subview as it has caused other problems in the code (reported in other SO questions and with no clean solution). So I try adding the Gesture to the superview instead.
I have tried the following code but it doesn't work as it doesn't detect when & where the gesture BEGAN.
  DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .updating($scrubberSeeking, body: { value, state, _ in
                        
                        if abs(value.startLocation.x - scrubberOffset) > 20.0  {
                            state = false
                            return
                        }
                        
                        state = true
                    })
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        
                            if scrubberSeeking {
                                ...
                                ...
                            }
                       

                    })
                    .onEnded { value in
                        
                    }


To detect where the drag gesture first started,
try this approach storing the start of a drag into a var dragStartPosition in .onChanged.
Then resetting that var to nil in .onEnded after completing any desired logic,
as shown in the example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDragging = false
    @State private var dragStartPosition: CGPoint?
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isDragging ? Color.red : Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged { value in
                        if dragStartPosition == nil {
                            dragStartPosition = value.startLocation
                            print("---> dragStartPosition is: \(dragStartPosition)")
                            isDragging = true
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        if let startPosition = dragStartPosition {
                            print("------> startPosition was: \(startPosition)")
                        }
                        dragStartPosition = nil
                        isDragging = false
                    }
            )
    }
}

EDIT-1
code example to also drag the Circle as well as answering the question of how to
detect where the drag gesture first started.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDragging = false
    @State private var dragStartPosition: CGPoint?
    @State private var circlePos: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(isDragging ? Color.red : Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .position(circlePos)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged { value in
                        if dragStartPosition == nil {
                            dragStartPosition = value.startLocation
                            print("---> dragStartPosition is: \(dragStartPosition)")
                            isDragging = true
                        }
                        circlePos = value.location
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        if let startPosition = dragStartPosition {
                            print("------> startPosition was: \(startPosition)")
                        }
                        dragStartPosition = nil
                        isDragging = false
                    }
            )
    }
}


There are two issues with your code. First, you lock the ability to self-correct the user’s drag gesture while dragging, due to the condition in .onChanged. Second, there is no logic to account for whether the drag is to the left or right. This could be handled with a simple math calculation, using the start and end positions to determine the final drag direction.

Personally, I think the drag offset to the left or right should be used in the app for animations, such as fading in a red color or some UI element, to indicate the deletion process. This way, the animation can occur while dragging, but the delete command should only be triggered on .onEnded.

I have no idea what you are talking about, but for completion I added some example code to do the actual dragging of the Circle, ie change position.
